# Combining Eclipse for Java EE and CDT

Tags: java, c++, eclipse

I'm currently using separate Eclipse packages for Java EE and C/C++. Problem is that i have to download every plugin that is language agnostic (i.e. Git) twice. I'm aware that i can simply use Help->Install New Software in Java EE Eclipse package to add CDT there, but is that a good idea? 
In other words, if i use one Eclipse package for multiple languages, is there some drawbacks, bugs or other kinds of bad things that could happen, over simply using separate package for every language?

Comment: I have never had any problems running different languages in the same eclipse installation. I usually have `C++`, `Java`, `PHP` and general webtools (`XML` etc...) installed.

Comment: no except some performance (more memory consumption in eclipse ) issue due to the fact  that you would have a lot of plugins loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will really recommend use the Java part and the C++ part into two different eclipse projects. I don't think that it will work properly otherwise.Also, I think you will use one eclipse version with multiple plugins tends to make eclipse very messy.

> Problems occur because sometimes
>
> - Plugins are buggy
> - Plugins are incompatible with each other.
> - Different plugins rely on different versions of another one (indirectly incompatible).
> - Plugins don't work the way the rest of the tool does
> - There are just too many plugins to choose from - you don't need most, and the ones you need can be hard to find.

[How to add different programming languages to Eclipse (C++, C#, Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602862/how-to-add-different-programming-languages-to-eclipse-c-c-java)