# How to switch Eclipse from python back to Java

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I set up my Eclipse for python environment. Everything works fine. But how can I switch back to Java environment and create projects in Java?

[image]

If I try create new project - nothing really happens:
[image]

[image]

I do not see Java Perspective if I go `enter code here`Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Others...`
Does it mean Java is not installed?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add different programming languages to Eclipse (C++, C#, Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602862/how-to-add-different-programming-languages-to-eclipse-c-c-java)

Comment: Thanks, but I could not find a solution in a link above.

Comment: Create a Java project instead of a Python project?

Comment: I tried to. I edited question with screenshots

Comment: Do you actually have Java development installed in this Eclipse?

Comment: I think originally was Java, then I installed Python. But how would I check?

Comment: Is there a _Java_ perspective in _Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Others..._?

Comment: I do not see exactly Java perspective. I see: 
`Debug, 
PyDev, 
Resourse(Default), 
Team Synchronizing`

I edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the missing *Java* perspective, it is clear that your IDE does not provide Java support. To **install the *[Eclipse Java Development Tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-java-development-tools-0)*** do one of the following:

- [Drag this link and drop it on your running Eclipse IDE](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=3029282) (requires installed Eclipse Marketplace client)
- ***Help > Install New Software...***:

  1. In ***Work with:*** enter `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7/`
  2. Select ***Eclipse Java Development Tools***
  3. Press ***Next >*** and follow the instructions of the dialog

Answer (score 3):

It *should* be as simple as:

Eclipse > Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Java

or Perspective > Others > Java

Comment: I dont see Java perspective. Does it mean I have to install it?

Comment: Yup.  It sounds like you did a clean, Python-only install.  No probem.  Just go into Help > Eclipse Marketplace or Help > Install software, search for and install "Eclipse Java Development Tools"